# How to prohibit overwriting of Files

Tags: authorization, ntfs

I have applied NTFS permissions to help protect a few files from accidental deletion. All the features do prevent users from accidentally/purposefully delete files. However, I am unable to find a solution to the problem of avoiding overwriting of the files.

I unchecked the "Write Attributes" and "Write Extended Attributes", but that makes the files "Read-Only", which is not of much use. So, the question here is what tools/features do I use so that users may not accidentally/purposefully overwrite the files.

Any help in this regard would be really helpful.

Comment: Overwrite means initial deleting. Just deny deletion.

Comment: No. We tested that. Doesn't seem to prohibit overwrite. We have done all sorts of tests. We are not able to prohibit that. Just curious whether a DLP tool could help us with this.

Comment: You can set permissions to allow "write" but not modify. This will do, but there are limitation due to how programs like MSOffice work, meaning that you can create a file, but once closed, you can not delete or change it.

Comment: there's ways to set append-only in nix, not sure about windows.